# Is there a way to use inner join on a trigger to update a column

Tags: postgresql

I need to update a column based on another table column:

table products:
store_id
store_name

table stores:
id
name

So I need to when a new product is saved, the column store_name is updated with the store_name from stores table.

How to solve that?
Thanks

Comment: don't store information double normalize your structure and you don't need the trigger

Comment: Yes: Delete column `store_name` and instead join to `store` to get it.

Comment: not normalising your db: bad. Using triggers: usually a bad idea. Yes you can do what you ask but there are two very good reasons to normalise your database properly instead.

Comment: I can't delete any column. thats why I need a trigger
thanks anyway.

Comment: There's no such thing as "can't", but some things are harder to do and/or get permission to do than others. If you can't delete the column, you can still ignore it: just change the queries that use store_name to use the joined column instead.

Comment: If you cannot  change the table definition there is a DBA that can. Talk to your DBA. After all you and they are on the same team (even if not by organization or name) and have the same basic function: produce the best solution for your employer/client.